# How is the hash of a block in a bitcoin blockchain is 512 bits in size?

Tags: hash, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, sha256

How does hash of a block in a bitcoin blockchain is 512 bits in size given that it is encoded using SHA-256 algorithm that should have a 256 bits output ?

Comment: A block hash in Bitcoin is 256 bits.

Comment: Yaa it should be... I checked legit hashes and they turned out to be 512 bit.... Do check them yourself sir

Comment: I have, can you give an example?

Comment: I cannot add a image because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: You can paste the block hash, or a link to where you found it. Tell me what you're looking at, so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely treating the hash as a string and calculating the bits for the string.

A hex string takes up 2x the space as the same information represented in bytes. For instance, if a hash were `00`, the bitcoin protocol would treat it as a single byte, `0x00`.

Many other representations, however, would treat is as the string `"00"`, which translates to 0x3030, or two bytes.

If you have a 32 byte block hash in some program as a string, and you calculate the number of bits, you'll end up with 512 instead of 256.